# "last-update" time of an html document

Tags: javascript, html

This question is about pages like gmail or Facebook, which keep updating lively all the time.

If in a browser, such as UIWebView in iOS, where the live feeds do not seem to appear automatically, I wish to reload the page only if it was updated on the server. For this, is there a way to obtain last-update time of the document, something like the output of the unix command

```
 ls -ltr filename
```

for an html document on the web server?

Or in general, how is this kind of problem tackled?

Thanks in advance,
Nikhil

Comment: Send a request with the If-Modified-Since header and check for 304 response code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this JS snippet:

```
javascript:alert(document.lastModified)
```

I would however suggest to implement something yourself as this may not give you accurate result all the time. You can generate a hash of some part of the live feeds and save the hash. Next time re-generate the hash and compare that hash with the saved hash and if the hash doesn't match, it means the content of the feeds has changed. Trigger the update method to fetch new live feeds and replace the old hash with the new hash in your local database.

I hope it helps.